# Cordova facebook plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova

I'm new on Cordova. I want to Facebook login on my app. I decised to use this Facebook plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook4. İf a user click the login button I want to get name, surname and email from the user. I didn't understand exactly how to use. I determined some functions but I dont not where I have to use. For example

**Login**

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(Array strings of permissions, Function success, Function failure)
```

**Logout**

```
facebookConnectPlugin.logout(Function success, Function failure)
```

**This is login js**

```
var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
console.log("UserInfo: ", userData);
}

facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"], fbLoginSuccess,
function loginError (error) {
    console.error(error)
   }
);
```

Comment: They are lots of tutorials online that can help you. [Here](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework) is one of them.

Comment: does the login work? do you get any error? did you debug the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work to get the required data, after login:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api("me/?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email", ["email"],
  function onSuccess (result) {
    console.log("Result: ", result);
  }, function onError (error) {
    console.error("Failed: ", error);
  }
);
```

Btw, you need to authorize the user with the correct permissions(s):

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(["email"], fbLoginSuccess,
    function loginError (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
);
```

How to use the login code on button click:

```
document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", function() {
    facebookConnectPlugin.login(["email"], fbLoginSuccess,
        function loginError (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: How to call the function with a button?

Comment: how about a simple javascript click listener? i am not sure if that really is your question right now, to be honest...you should not even start with the facebook stuff if you don´t know how to call a function on button click...

Comment: Your solution is correct. For example I created a button id is login. I have to call your function as document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", facebookConnectPlugin.login()); ?

Comment: you need to specify a callback function, not call the login function...oh boy...i will add a small code part to my answer